# keras exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) after running training 2 models

Tags: python, keras

I use Pycharm to run my script.
I have a script that loops. Each loop:
1. Select a dataset.
2. Trains a new Keras model.
3. Evaluate that model.

So the code works perfectly for 2 weeks but when installing a new anaconda environment, the code suddenly fails after two iteration of that loop.

Two models of Siamese Neural Network will train perfectly fine and right before the third loop, it crashes with Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

```
 1/32 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5075
12/32 [==========>...................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5112
27/32 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4700
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.4805
eval run time : 0.046851396560668945

For LOOCV run 2 out of 32. Model is SNN. Time taken for instance = 6.077638149261475
Post-training results: 
acc = 1.0 , ce = 0.6019332906978302 , f1 score = 1.0 , mcc = 0.0
cm = 
[[1]]
####################################################################################################

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

The strange thing is that the code used to work perfectly fine and even when I am not using the anaconda enviornment and used the previous environment I used, it still exits with the same exit code.

When I use a another type of model (a dense neural network), it also crashes but after 4 iteration. Is it something to do with running out of memory? This is an example of the loop. The exact model does not matter, it always crashes after a certain number of loops at the train model line (Between point 2 and 3)

```
 # Run k model instance to perform skf
    predicted_labels_store = []
    acc_store = []
    ce_store = []
    f1s_store = []
    mcc_store = []
    folds = []
    val_features_c = []
    val_labels = []
    for fold, fl_tuple in enumerate(fl_store):
        instance_start = time.time()
        (ss_fl, i_ss_fl) = fl_tuple  # ss_fl is training fl, i_ss_fl is validation fl
        if model_mode == 'SNN':
            # Run SNN
            model = SNN(hparams, ss_fl.features_c_dim)
            loader = Siamese_loader(model.siamese_net, ss_fl, hparams)
            loader.train(loader.hparams.get('epochs', 100), loader.hparams.get('batch_size', 32),
                         verbose=loader.hparams.get('verbose', 1))
            predicted_labels, acc, ce, cm, f1s, mcc = loader.eval(i_ss_fl)
            predicted_labels_store.extend(predicted_labels)
            acc_store.append(acc)
            ce_store.append(ce)
            f1s_store.append(f1s)
            mcc_store.append(mcc)
        elif model_mode == 'cDNN':
            # Run DNN
            print('Point 1')
            model = DNN_classifer(hparams, ss_fl)
            print('Point 2')
            model.train_model(ss_fl)
            print('Point 3')
            predicted_labels, acc, ce, cm, f1s, mcc = model.eval(i_ss_fl)
            predicted_labels_store.extend(predicted_labels)
            acc_store.append(acc)
            ce_store.append(ce)
            f1s_store.append(f1s)
            mcc_store.append(mcc)
        del model
        K.clear_session()
        instance_end = time.time()
        if cv_mode == 'skf':
            print('\nFor k-fold run {} out of {}. Model is {}. Time taken for instance = {}\n'
                  'Post-training results: \nacc = {} , ce = {} , f1 score = {} , mcc = {}\ncm = \n{}\n'
                  '####################################################################################################'
                  .format(fold + 1, k_folds, model_mode, instance_end - instance_start, acc, ce, f1s, mcc, cm))
        else:
            print('\nFor LOOCV run {} out of {}. Model is {}. Time taken for instance = {}\n'
                  'Post-training results: \nacc = {} , ce = {} , f1 score = {} , mcc = {}\ncm = \n{}\n'
                  '####################################################################################################'
                  .format(fold + 1, fl.count, model_mode, instance_end - instance_start, acc, ce, f1s, mcc, cm))
        # Preparing output dataframe that consists of all the validation dataset and its predicted labels
        folds.extend([fold] * i_ss_fl.count)  # Make a col that contains the fold number for each example
        val_features_c = np.concatenate((val_features_c, i_ss_fl.features_c_a),
                                        axis=0) if val_features_c != [] else i_ss_fl.features_c_a
        val_labels.extend(i_ss_fl.labels)
        K.clear_session()
```

And the exit code for a dense neural network.

```
For LOOCV run 4 out of 32. Model is cDNN. Time taken for instance = 0.7919328212738037
Post-training results: 
acc = 0.0 , ce = 0.7419472336769104 , f1 score = 0.0 , mcc = 0.0
cm = 
[[0 1]
 [0 0]]
####################################################################################################
Point 1
Point 2

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you!.

Comment: I quote: `The most typical causes for the ‘0xC0000005: Access Violation’ error are: corrupt registry, malware, faulty RAM or device driver, incorrectly written, installed or updated software or even Windows security features.` More specific to your issue when a program attempts to access memory which has been distributed to another process and is not available for this one, you'll receive the error and the program will be terminated.

Comment: Then what should I do? I have no idea why this issue would suddenly pop up when it was working fine a day ago :(

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the line for `for` loop while creating DNN?

Comment: Okay I added the full loop in. It does not matter if the mode is SNN or cDNN.
Also, I have another scrip that is similar to this but slightly different and it also has the same exit code :(

Comment: Also, I reinstalled python, pycharm, anaconda3 and all the packages and the problem still occurs...

Comment: It's little hard to find the issue, seeing the incomplete code. e.g. How `SNN` or `DNN_classifer` class is defined. My best guess for the issue (if it is in the code) is some messed up memory access. Can you try explicitly setting new session at the start of each loop like `sess = tf.Session(); K.set_session(sess)` and then deleting variable `loader` as well and calling `gc.collect()` at the end of loop.

Comment: Oh my goodness it works after I added 1) New tf session 2) del model and del loader 3) gc.collect() at the end. It works for all my loop scripts now. But why would it work? I try removing 1 or 2 of those 3 things and the exit code always appears but before today, it used to be fine without any of the 3 things you told me to add...

Comment: added explanation as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the explanation for the things I suggested in the comments that worked, in case anyone faces the same issue.

Manually setting session for keras rather than using the default one at the start of each loop.

```
sess = tf.Session()  
K.set_session(sess) 
#..... train your model
K.clear_session()
```

Deleting `loader` variable as this object must be having reference to the original `model` object as I can see you are calling the `train()` on it.

Explicitly collecting all the memory released by deleting these the variable using `gc.collect()` after each loop so that we have enough memory for building our new model.

So, the gist is when running multiple independent model in a loop like this make sure you have explicitly set the tensorflow session so that you can clear this session after loop finishes, releasing all the resources uses by this session. Delete all the references that might be tied to tensorflow objects in that loop and collect the free memory.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! However, do you know how I can add more free memory to my python/ pycharm? Because my laptop has 16gb RAM and when I was checking my task manager, when the script was running it does not exceed 1.3gb RAM. So why does the memory run out?

Comment: @LimKaizhuo  The issue might not be because of your RAM is not enough for one model. But because if we say in layman's terms the program was using memory allocated to one model inside another model before that memory was freed. But I am not sure considering you are using Windows and PyCharm, why the task manager shows total memory usage only 1.3 GB.