# Sound way of managing multiple sessions and graphs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'd like to manage multiple Keras models in multiple sessions. My application is constructed such that models can be live at the same time, in addition to creating, saving and loading them.

**What is the proper way of managing this situation?**

Currently one model is represented by an instance of a wrapper class. This is used in the training, saving, loading and prediction. One `tf.Graph` and `tf.Session` is created per instance, and they are used in every function requiring the actual model.

```
class NN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        self.session = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)

    def predict(self, x):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            with self.session.as_default():
                return self.model.predict(x)
```

Similar functions using the `with` statements are created for compiling the network, fitting, saving (weights to .h5 and model to JSON) and loading. So whenever the model is needed, the graph and session are brought to context.

This resulted in a strange error ([Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002518/poor-exit-code-when-managing-multiple-sessions) for further context), and I was left wondering, what is the standard way of dealing with this. I tried to release all possible resources before creating or loading a model, but it hasn't helped. This function is just a compilation of all possible routines scraped off the internet, and is purely guesswork.

```
def _new_session(self):
    if self.session is not None:
        self.session.close()
    k.clear_session()
    gc.collect()
    self.graph = tf.Graph()
    self.session = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)
```

I've not found good documentation of a similar situation. So I'd very much appreciate any real insight into this.

---

I might need to delete the old question, as it's quite all over the place. At the time of asking I had no idea what was going on. But it's there for now.

---

Some specific questions have arisen.

- Loading and making predictions on a model works, compiling and fitting doesn't, although just compiling does. Do the two contexts differ in any way? Is the loaded model exactly the same?
- At which points should a new context be created when manipulating the models? (e.g. at load, compilation, fitting, probably not with every prediction)
- Which actions are necessary to take when releasing the resources of previous contexts? Either when a network is disposed of or when creating a new context.
- Why exactly is the context switch needed for multiple models?
- What are the roles of graph vs. session, given that different things are executed on the graph and session?

#### Updates

- Compiling, fitting and saving one network works without any context trickery. Doing the same for another model in the same context works too (or at least does not produce an error).
- In addition to above, **loading the saved model and predicting works too**, right after the training and for both models! Now I'm not sure whether the prediction is made correctly, but again, no error. This only begs the question I posed above even more: *why are the different contexts needed?*

---

The underlying issue with the error has been finally (and somewhat embarassingly) [resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002518/poor-exit-code-when-managing-multiple-sessions) by updating all packages.

Comment: try tf.reset_default_graph() ? I really dont know if it will help or net, but when i was loading multiple models using multiple graphs, this helped

Comment: @ImtinanAzhar Where did you use it? Using it at the end of `_new_session` had no effect.

Comment: every time a load a model, thats where i used it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Actually, seeing again how `K.get_session()` works, it should return the current default session, so I'm not sure `set_session` is doing anything meaningful there. I'll leave the answer just in case you want to try but probably this won't help.

---

Maybe you can get it to work with something like this:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

class NN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        self.session = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)

    def predict(self, x):
        with self._context():
            return self.model.predict(x)

    @contextmanager
    def _context(self):
        prev_sess = K.get_session()
        K.set_session(self.session)
        with self.graph.as_default(), self.session.as_default():
            yield
        K.set_session(prev_sess)
```

Note that the Keras session object is a global variable, so I suppose this should work as long as you don't try to use these contexts from multiple threads.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The context manager seems like a good way of going about it. However, it did not solve the underlying problem. It's odd to me, that when just loading a model and making predictions, everything is fine, but it's the training (compile + fit) where things collapse. So do you happen to know do the two processes differ in any way? Now that I think about it, it really should've been in the question also..