# Part 3: Switching between multiple contexts - no error and a bad exit code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've been struggling with managing multiple Keras models with `tf.Graphs` and `tf.Sessions` for several weeks now. In short, I'd like to have multiple models open and switch between them as needed. This includes training new models, opening from file and making predictions.

The bottom line is: (almost) everything works fine until the program crashes with exit code `0xC0000005`. No error messages are given. Let me explain.

- I can load a model and make predictions on it. Results are recieved, and after printing them, the program crashes.
- I can load multiple models and make predictions on them. Then the program crashes.
- I can create a new model, and make predictions on it. Finally, the program crashes.
- I cannot create two models, even the same model twice with different instances of the class below. The program crashes.

You get the point. This is how I currently manage the graphs and sessions. I use a context manager to set the created graph and session as defaults and later switch to the previous state.

```
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        self.session = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)
        self.model = None

    def close(self):
        self.session.close()
        del self.graph
        self.graph = None
        gc.collect()

    @contextmanager
    def _context(self):
        prev = k.get_session()
        k.set_session(self.session)
        with self.graph.as_default(), self.session.as_default():
            yield
        k.set_session(prev)

    def predict(self, x):
        with self._context():
            return self.model.predict(x)

    def fit(self, x_train, y_train, n=20, batch=256):
        with self._context():
            self.model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=n, batch_size=batch, verbose=0)

    def create(self, shape):
        with self._context():
            self.model = Sequential()
            self.model.add(Dense(shape[1], input_dim=shape[0], activation='relu'))
            self.model.add(Dropout(drop))
            self.model.add(Dense(shape[2], activation='sigmoid'))
            self.model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

    def load(self, path, sfx=''):
        with open(path / ('architecture' + sfx + '.json'), 'r') as f:
            js = f.read()

        with self._context():
            self.model = model_from_json(js)
            self.model.load_weights(path / ('weights' + sfx + '.h5'))
            self.model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

    def save(self, path, sfx=''):
        path.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        with self._context():
            js = self.model.to_json()
            with open(path / ('architecture' + sfx + '.json'), 'w') as f:
                f.write(js)
            self.model.save_weights(path / ('weights' + sfx + '.h5'))
```

And with the above class, here's how a network is used elsewhere:

```
def create(self):
    x, y = [], []
    shape = (15, 30, 1)

    self.predictor = NeuralNetwork()
    self.predictor.create(shape)
    self.predictor.fit(x, y)
    self.predictor.save(path=self.path)
    self.predictor.close()

def load(self):
    self.predictor.load(path=self.path)

def predict(x):
    # Executed only on loaded networks, never on created networks
    # due to program structure
    return self.predictor.predict(x)
```

Here are my previous efforts at articulating the problem.

- [Part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002518/poor-exit-code-when-managing-multiple-sessions), the one where I had no clue
- [Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53206900/sound-way-of-managing-multiple-sessions-and-graphs), the one where I started to figure things out

To the best of my abilities and with the help of some people, I've tried to come up with a way to manage these resources (context manager and "closing" the network after training). But I have not come across documentation or a tutorial describing the process of Tensorflow or Keras resource management in detail.

---

My goals are two-fold.

- First and foremost, get rid of this error
- Hopefully learn the absolutely correct way of dealing with this scenario

If you can help me achieve or even step a tiny amount towards the direction of either one, I'd greatly appreciate it! I have the experience, that my struggles are neither unique nor something that others haven't already thought of. So I must just be lacking the proper approach.

Comment: This error keeps sounding so strange. You can have many sorts of error with Keras/TensorFlow/Python, but you should never get a segmentation fault (`0xC0000005`). Have you already checked that all versions (including CUDA and CuDNN) are compatible, updated GPU drivers, and/or tried to run things in a new clean virtualenv (or even a different machine)?

Comment: @jdehesa First of all, thank you for the continuing help. I really appreciate it. Agreed, it's a weird thing to happen. Though, I've heard the error is a common Windows error, not just segfault. But I may have read sources that have simplified things for common users of programs. I have the CPU version of TF, so to my knowledge the GPU issues don't apply. I'll try another environment or a machine and get back to you.

Comment: Oh I thought you were using GPU, CPU-only makes it even weirder. You're right that `0xC0000005` is also described as a more general error by some, tbh it's impossible to tell when it's supposed to happen without official docs from Microsoft, which are ridiculously missing. Testing in another setup is a pain but if it fails consistently I think this is for TF devs to fix. I don't think that's the problem, but old CPUs may fail since version [1.6.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/v1.6.0) due to AVX instructions (but I don't think you'd be able to run anything if it were that).

Comment: @jdehesa It appears I was too quick to blame my own stupidity and look for an error in the code, though it was very beneficial to go through the context manager. For a clean `venv` and exactly same installation, the error was reproduced, but it vanished when updating all packages. So it probably was fixed in some TF release between 1.8 and 1.12 (intentionally or not). I'm embarassed, that I didn't perform this basic check. But thank you! I'd be happy to accept an answer if this is worth writing an answer to..

Comment: Oh great, I'm glad you got it working! No stupidity, these things happen all the time :) Thanks for the feedback on that, it's actually good to know that there was such a nasty error in some past release and it got fixed later. Maybe you can answer your own question here, in case someone comes across this, just indicating that upgrading from one version to another fixed it (or whatever else you had to do). You can also include a link in your previous questions, for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by updating all packages to their latest versions. Sadly, I made the upgrading in one go, which means I'm not sure what actually was the cause. But I'm willing to bet on Tensorflow.

Here are the package versions most likely involved in producing the error and their updated versions:

- `tensorflow==1.8.0 -> 1.12.0`
- `numpy==1.14.5 -> 1.15.4`
- `scikit-learn==0.19.1 -> 0.20.0`